# need to add crash reporting functionality in wp8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, error-reporting

I have developed a Windows Phone app in WP7.1 and WP8. I need to implement crash reporting functionality to my app. Whenever a force-close happens, I'd like to get all the details of what happened. Does anyone know the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 5):

The [diagnostics element of Telerik's Windows Phone control suite](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/diagnostics.aspx) includes error reporting.

Alternatively, you could look at one of the many [Little Watson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx) implementations.

Comment: Hi Thank you,

I am trying this telerik control, I guess that it is a 30days trial, is it so.

If so what will happen after 30days,

if i add this controls in my app, will it work after 30days.

Comment: The app will continue to work and will [display a random trial message](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/devcraft.aspx#ctl00_ctl00_GeneralBox_Content_ListDisplay1_ctl00_ctl00_lists_ctl06_listItems_ctl01_headlineContainer) - but it's illegal to submit the app to the Windows Phone Store if you haven't purchased a license for the controls.

Answer (score 2):

On WP8 you can use Flurry which has an event handler for Unhandled Exceptions. It's not incredibly detailed I've noticed but it's free. The advantage being you can throw log error calls around to try and narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com) and am very happy with it. Beside the crash reporting with notifications, you also get nice statistics, like which app version on which device is the most affected by a problem and so on. Usage is as simple as referencing the assembly and calling one init function, although you can customize what gets reported (custom values like a userId or some other metric). They provide free and paid versions of the system. The support has also been great. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try yandex appmetrica for win phone https://github.com/yandexmobile/metrica-sample-dotnet